# Intl.NumberFormat throws error "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid currency code"

Tags: javascript

I want to write a format function to show prices in euros, but it throws an error. What is wrong?

```js
const formatVal = val => new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "€"
}).format(val)

formatVal(456)
```

The error that is being thrown:

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid currency code : â¬

Comment: `currency: "EUR"`

Comment: If `style` property has a value of `currency`, then the `currency` property is required to specify the three-letter ISO currency code (such as "USD" for US dollars or "GBP" for British pounds) of the desired currency. In you case, you want euro currency, so `EUR` should do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change € to EUR

```js
const formatVal = val => new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "EUR"
}).format(val)

console.log(formatVal(456))
```

Answer (score 1):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#Parameters):

> The currency to use in currency formatting. Possible values are the
> ISO 4217 currency codes, such as "`USD`" for the US dollar, "`EUR`"
> for the euro, or "`CNY`" for the Chinese RMB — see the [Current
> currency & funds code list](https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html). There is no default value; if the
> `style` is "`currency`", the `currency` property must be provided.

`€` is not a valid ISO 4217 currency code. Use `EUR` instead.

Comment: empirically any three letters are accepted, even if they are not a known currency code (but four letters are not accepted)